# How to make a list-child with javascript and jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Hi everyone i want to make a list from a short code

I want to move (with javascript or jQuery) from this:

```
<ul id='nav'>
  <li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>Sub-menu</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>_Sub-Menu child 1</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>_Sub-Menu child 2</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>_Sub-Menu child 3</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>__Sub-Menu child 3.1</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>__Sub-Menu child 3.2</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>__Sub-Menu child 3.3</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>Example</a></li>
</ul>
```

To this :

```
<ul id='nav'>
  <li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
  <li class='hasSub1'>
    <a href='#'>Sub-menu</a>
    <ul class='subMenu1'>
     <li><a href='#'>Sub-Menu child 1</a></li>
     <li><a href='#'>Sub-Menu child 2</a></li>
     <li class='hasSub2'>
       <a href='#'>Sub-Menu child 3</a>
       <ul class='subMenu2'>
         <li><a href='#'>Sub-Menu child 3.1</a></li>
         <li><a href='#'>Sub-Menu child 3.2</a></li>
         <li><a href='#'>Sub-Menu child 3.3</a></li>
       </ul>
     </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href='#'>Example</a></li>
</ul>
```

The Method is when someone make a list and use "_" this second list be inside the before list or the double of "__" like the example that i make, and also we can make an infinite list like this method not just one time.

I tried to make the first level of the script `_`
This is what i make:

```
<script>
               $("#LinkList1").each(function() {
               var e = "<ul id='nav'><li><ul id='sub-menu'>";
               $("#LinkList1 li").each(function() {
                   var t = $(this).text(),
                       n = t.substr(0, 1),
                       r = t.substr(1);
                   "_" == n ? (n = $(this).find("a").attr("href"), e += '<li><a href="' + n + '" class="list-name"><span class="lint-span">' + r + "</span></a></li>") : (n = $(this).find("a").attr("href"), e += '</ul></li><li><a href="' + n + '" class="list-name"><span class="lint-span">' + t + "</span></a><ul id='sub-menu'>")
               });
               e += "</ul></li></ul>";
               $(this).html(e);
               $("#LinkList1 ul").each(function() {
                   var e = $(this);
                   if (e.html().replace(/\s|&nbsp;/g, "").length == 0) e.remove()
               });
               $("#LinkList1 li").each(function() {
                   var e = $(this);
                   if (e.html().replace(/\s|&nbsp;/g, "").length == 0) e.remove()
               })
           });$('#sub-menu').parent().addClass('hasSub');
</script>
```

Note that : #LinkList1 is a Div (Parent of All elements) and just adding a class and span in the element but when i tried to make the second Level `__` (two _) it doesn't work for me perfectly paisley when we all a multiple list

Comment: So how much are you offering for someone to write the code for you?  :)  Please write some code, and if you can't get it to work, then update the question showing the code with specifics about what is not working.

Comment: i make a code for the first  "_"  child but i don't know how i can make  the "___"
it can't work

Comment: We are not a code-writing service here... what have you tried?

Comment: I make the first level of this script work perfectly using _ to make the first child but for the second level '__' i have some problems working with a lot of list so i asked this question to find the solution i want to know from the beginning all the steps even when i explain my idea it may confuse you and in the final we will not have the solution

Comment: I edit the question you can find my attempt :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have create a function with each `<a>` into your nav menu list.

Please try below:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var list = $("<ul />");
  $("ul#nav a").each(function(i,e){
    var iter = $($(this).html().match(/\_/g)).length;
var href = $(this).attr("href");
    if(iter>0){
        if(list.find("ul").hasClass("subMenu"+iter)){
          list.find(".subMenu" + iter).append("<li><a href='"+ href +"'>" + $(this).text().substr(iter) + "</a></li>");
        }else{
          list.find("li").last().append("<ul class='subMenu"+iter+"'><li><a href='"+ href +"'>" + $(this).text().substr(iter) + "</a></li></ul>").addClass("hasSub"+iter);
        }
    }else{
        list.append("<li><a href='"+href+"'>" + $(this).text() + "</a></li>");
    }
  })
  $("#nav").empty().append(list);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id='nav' >
  <li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>Sub-menu</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>_Sub-Menu child 1</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>_Sub-Menu child 2</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>_Sub-Menu child 3</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>__Sub-Menu child 3.1</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>__Sub-Menu child 3.2</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>__Sub-Menu child 3.3</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>___Sub-Menu child 3.3.1</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>Example</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for this replay but can you eliminate the style='display:none;' from the ul :)

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer and your help you make a good attempt but sorry it not useful for me because you remove the hole ul and i don't want to remove the ul i need to add and make this changes without removing or appending the list

Comment: Ok no prob. I have clear the actual data list and replace by the new list. Please try now

Comment: Nice, but we still have a problem in the href=''#" may the customer change the href 
We must maintain the same href

Comment: Ok i have get the actual href. Please try now.

Answer (score 0):

Think this will help you..:D

```js
function changer(){
  var first = $('#nav li');
  var inserter = '';
  var _counter,prev = 0;
  while(typeof first.html() != "undefined"){
    var len = $(first.html().match(/\_/g)).length;
    if(len>prev) while(len>prev){inserter += '<ul clas="Submenu'+len+'">';prev++;}
    else if(len<prev) while(len<prev){inserter += '</ul>';prev--;}
    inserter += '<li>'+first.html().replace(/\_/g,'')+'</li>'; 
    first = first.next();
  }
  while(prev>0){insert += "</ul>";prev--;}
  $('#nav').empty().append(inserter);
}
$(document).ready(function(){
  changer();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id='nav'>
  <li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>Sub-menu</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>_Sub-Menu child 1</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>_Sub-Menu child 2</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>_Sub-Menu child 3</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>__Sub-Menu child 3.1</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>__Sub-Menu child 3.2</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>__Sub-Menu child 3.3</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>Example</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply
But we still have the _ and __ in the final

Answer (score -4):

Do you mean that when you press for example "hasSub1" it expands and shows "subMenu1" (which was hidden before)?

```
Jquery:
$(document).ready(function(){
$( "a" ).click(function() {
$(this).siblings().toggle();
});
});
```

Comment: I don't see your problem then. You want people to insert the first code and when they do it converts to the second?

Comment: You use the Click function
we don't want when the user click on the a
when the user use the first structure they get the second code that i make
that's all